# Nitric Oxide Dimerization

Tags: bond, energy, molecular-orbital-theory

This is the molecular orbital diagram for nitric oxide:

[image]

Now, we know that nitric oxide can dimerize. However, why does nitric oxide dimerize as to form an $\ce{N-N}$ bond? Why not an $\ce{O-O}$ bond? Wouldn't the lone electron be more likely "possessed" by the oxygen since oxygen is more electronegative (if we were to step away from molecular orbital theory for a second).

Is this a Coulombic effect? Oxygen, by nature of being more electronegative, attracts more electron density to itself. This in turn would weaken any hypothetical $\ce{O-O}$ bond due to electron-electron repulsions.

Comment: >This is the molecular orbital diagram for nitric oxide || It shows oxygen having orbitals with higher energy, which is obviously wrong. Please, check. As for the question, the $\ce{ONN}$ angle in N2O2 is ~100, so I would say the nature of the bond is debatable. While antibonding orbital obviously is shifted towards atom with higher initial orbitals, the angles suggests partial O-O or O-N interactions as well.

Comment: What does bond angle suggest about the nature of the bond, exactly? How can you conclude that there are O-O interactions based on angles?

Comment: Oh wait nvm I see it after I drew out the diagram; the 100 degree bond angles deviate from the usual sp3 hybridized bond angle; this suggests that the oxygens may be interacting with each other and closing up the bond angle from 109.5 degrees. Are there really available orbitals on the oxygens to do this/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is not correct with your MO diagram.  Here is a correct MO diagram for NO

[image]

Note that in this diagram the oxygen atomic orbitals are lower in energy than the nitrogen AOs.  This makes sense since the AOs of the more electronegative element should always be at lower energy than the AOs of the more electropositive element (in your diagram the relative energies of the oxygen and nitrogen AOs are somehow reversed).  The energetic ordering of the starting AOs is important as we'll see in a minute.

The closer in energy a MO is to an AO from which it was formed, the more character of that AO it shows.  So let's examine the nature of the single electron in the $\ce{\pi_{2p}^{\ast}}$ orbital since this electron will be involved in forming the new bond when $\ce{NO}$ dimerizes.  This MO is formed from both the nitrogen and oxygen p atomic orbitals, but it is closer in energy to the nitrogen p AO.  Therefore, we would expect this electron to have more nitrogen and less oxygen character (in other words it will reside more around nitrogen than oxygen).  Because this electron has greater density on nitrogen, dimerization to form an N-N bond is more likely than dimerization to form an O-O bond.

Comment: Are the AOs of the more EN element necessarily always lower in energy? Aren't there cases in which size trumps EN (i.e. with the binary halide series of acids)?

Comment: Also by "more likely" you're not excluding the possibility of the formation of a dimer with a peroxide linkage?

Comment: I think it would be "always", but I'm reluctant to use "always" so let me say "generally" the more EN atom will be at lower energy.

Comment: "more likely" addresses the kinetics of the situation.  There is a larger coefficient on N than O in the $\ce{\pi^{\ast}}$ orbital.  So initial bond formation involving N is more likely, but certainly (assuming there is some coefficient on O) oxygen bond formation could occur too, just to a lesser extent.  Now enter thermodynamics - no matter what predominates initially (kinetically), since the reaction is reversible, eventually we will wind up with a product equilibrium distribution matching the free energy difference between the isomers.

Comment: Cool. But I don't see any papers exploring the isomer of the nitric oxide dimer with an O-O linkage. Why not?

Comment: Using standard bond energies calculate the heats of formation of the 2 isomers.  If the difference is 3 kcal/m or more,  then the equilibrium mix will be > 99:1

Comment: So we can safely ignore entropies of formation?

Comment: For a back of the envelope calculation - yes.  Further, in this case, I would expect the two reactions to be very similar entropically.

Comment: Using this table (http://www.kentchemistry.com/links/Kinetics/BondEnergy.htm) it appears there is a difference of about 17 kcal/mole. Huge!

Comment: How are you relating enthalpies of formation to product mixtures? I'm guessing you are using dG = -RTlnK in some form or fashion?

Comment: Exactly, so with a 17 kcal/m difference K ~ 10^12 !!!

Comment: Why would a peroxide linkage be weaker than a N-N linkage?

Comment: That would make another good question.

Comment: And how are you using dG=-RTlnK to arrive at K? This is my train of thought: TdS is ~ equal for both the formations of ONNO and NOON, so dG for the two should differ by 17 kJ/mol. Then 17 kJ/mol = -RTlnK, and for K I get 0.99.

Comment: Could this be because I forgot to convert R = 8.31J/(mol*K) to a kJ/(mol*K) value?

Comment: 17 kcal/mol or kJ/mol?

Comment: It is 17kJ/mol. http://www.kentchemistry.com/links/Kinetics/BondEnergy.htm. So 17kJ/mol is ~ 4kcal/mol and this suggests a >100:1 ratio in favor of the ONNO isomer versus the NOON isomer. I see where I screwed up!

Comment: "are you using dG=-RTlnK to arrive at K"? Yes, I get K ~ 1200 if delta G ~ 17 kJ/mol

Comment: you can always to a quick check: 1 power of 10 for each 1.4 kcal/mol at RT

Comment: You might want to continue the discussion in [chat].